# Squares and geometric series

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, diophantine-equations, geometric-series

Recently I've interested in the question: What is the relation between squares and sum of geometric series? In particular, I'm studying the following diophantine equation:

$a^n -1 = (a - 1) m^2$

I'm looking for positive solutions.

I want to know:

- Are there any bases $a$ with infinite number of solutions?
- Is there any efficient method to find nontrivial solutions for a given base?

I was able to prove unsolvability for specific bases $a$ and powers $p$, but not in general.

For instance, the case of $a = 3$ has two positive solutions: $p = 2, m = 2$ and $p = 5, m = 11$.

Can you help me with the general case? I'm trying to apply the theory of cyclotomic polynomials, but no luck so far.

Comment: For $n>2$ , I only found the solutions $a=3,n=5$ and $a=7,n=4$. For $n=2$ there are trivially infinite many solution , but this is not the question. I guess for every base , there are only finite many solutions.

Comment: $n=1$ and $m=1$ is also a trivial solution which we should rule out.

Comment: This is a specific instance of the Nagell-Ljunggren equation, and this specific instance is solved. The solution listed in the comment above are the only integral solutions, see here: https://www.jstor.org/stable/24493413

Comment: @Servaes Nice !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a specific instance of the Nagell-Ljunggren equation, and this specific instance is solved. The solutions
$$(a,m,n)=(3,11,5),\qquad\text{ and }\qquad (a,m,n)=(7,20,4)$$
listed in the comment above are the only integral solutions with $a,m,n>1$, see also here: https://www.jstor.org/stable/24493413

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).